# Azure Service Bus Behaviour if exception is thrown

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an Azure function app running in isolated mode. The function App has a Service Bus Trigger and consumes messages from a Service Bus Topic/Subscription.

```
[Function("ConsumeMessage")]
public async Task ConsumeMessage(
[ServiceBusTrigger("%MyTopic%","%MySubscription%",Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
string servicebusMessage)
{
        throw new Exception();
}
```

What I am noticing is that the message gets removed from the subscription even if the the function app throws an exception. I am not seeing the message in Dead-letter either.

In what situation does the message get dequeued and get sent again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the Azure Function Service Bus Trigger with .NET 6 Project to receive the message sent to the Topic-Subscription from the Logic App.

All the messages are receiving perfectly to the Service Bus Topic Subscription subscribed by the Function Trigger.

> I am not seeing the message in Dead-letter either.

To get the messages in dead letter queue, there are many ways as specified in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues#moving-messages-to-the-dlq) of ASB DLQ. I have followed one of the step is TTL Operation.

1. Changed TTL to 5 Minutes
2. Enabled dead letter queue on existing service bus topic-subscription
3. Run the Logic App configured to send the messages for the ASN Topic-Subscription.
4. Didn't run my Function App Service Bus Trigger to consume the messages.
5. After 5 minutes of TTL, message went to Dead letter Queue.

[image]

After 5 minutes of every message:

[image]

Also, in the same MS Document there is a section of how to reprocess the dead letter queue using Code or using SB Explorer.